# Jmetal - how to create start population from solution

Tags: java, optimization, module, heuristics

How do I start jMetal using a previous result as the initial population set?

I want to run jMetal. Then, with the obtained solutions, use them as the starting population and run Jmetal again.

Is there a way to do this?

(I am new using jMetal version 4.5.2 http://jmetal.sourceforge.net/ )

Thank you!